# Mounting network drive in Windows 10 bash?

Tags: windows-10, bash, mount

In my windows 10 command prompt, when I need to set the drive to some network shared drive I just use

```
net use V: //192.168.xxx.xxx/folder
```

I added Bash on Ubuntu on Windows in my Windows 10, and I'd like to have access to my network drives from the terminal as well, so I tried mounting it

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername //192.168.xxx.xxx/folder /mnt/new_folder
```

where I created my `new_folder` in the `/mnt` folder, but I get the error

> sudo: cannot find computer COMPUTER NAME

Where `COMPUTER NAME` is the actual name of my computer that I can see in the Explorer as well.

What am I doing wrong and how can I mount network drives in my windows bash?

EDIT:

I got it to work partially, by adding my computer name in the hosts file in `etc/hosts`

```
 127.0.1.1    COMPUTER NAME
```

But I still cannot mount the network drive

Comment: Those can't be the exact commands you used. Please use the exact commands. You state `network path` where you should have put `COMPUTERNAME`. Also don't use spaces in folders or put them between ". Remove the hosts entry. It just redirects the COMPUTER_NAME back to your own computer (which is not what you want). Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1127418/edit) with the exact commands you use.

Comment: Instead of network path I used my remote servers remote address (in my office), so it's along the line of `192.168.xxx.xxx/newtork_folder`. There are no spaces in the original, maybe I wasn't clear with that.

Comment: Well, that all matters a lot in your question. (you had `network path` right after `//` which should be the computername. Can you ping the computer by its ip or computername?

Comment: `I added Bash on Ubuntu on Windows in my Windows 10` O, wait... is this all on the same computer? How are you running Ubuntu on Windows?

Comment: The bash is on Windows (I'm testing it out, the new anniversary update), the remote server is on the same network as my laptop.

Comment: @Rik http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/ :D

Comment: Can you do `sudo ping 192.168.xxx.xxx` ?

Comment: Nope, I get `ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied`, and `sudo cannot find computer COMPUTER NAME`. I tried adding `-p` flag to mount but that didn't help

Comment: It could be that you need to run bash as administrator. See http://superuser.com/questions/1108133/cant-ping-in-bash-on-windows

Comment: Ok, now I can ping the remote server just fine

Comment: Ok, now you can also connect to a share. But I'm not sure if you're going to see any files. It might be that Bash for Windows is still in beta. http://superuser.com/questions/1114272/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-mount-network-share

Answer (score 9):

Support for WSL accessible mounting of network drives (as well as removable local drives) was [announced April 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/). Not sure which build exactly was the first to include it but my guess is around 15063.250 and above should be recent enough. If you do have support then you can now run:

`sudo mount -t drvfs '\\192.168.xxx.xxx\folder' /mnt/new_folder`

(Note that the network path must be in expressed in backslashes and thus has to be quoted to stop the shell automatically turning them into forward slashes.)

Answer (score -5):

See Callum Gare's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1250579/700617) above:
WSL has been under heavy development and it now supports mounting network shared folders.

---

**Old answer**

What you refer to as Windows 10 Bash is excellent for some uses but totally crippled for others. In general, it can be of good use for developers but is useless to SysAdmins. This is intentional, at least at the moment. It could just mean that it's under heavy development and some features are out of the current focus, as Rik [points out](https://superuser.com/questions/1114272/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-mount-network-share) and some people [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1128634/how-to-access-network-mounted-drive-on-windows-linux-subsystem) on superuser also believe. Another view on the matter is that it must not enter in competition with Powershell, which is the #1 Microsoft shell product at the moment.

It all depends on what your specific needs are. If all you need is Bash I would recommend doing yourself a favor and use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org) for now. Or [cmder](https://superuser.com/questions/1128634/how-to-access-network-mounted-drive-on-windows-linux-subsystem), which doesn't require installation.

After the long preamble, I'd like to answer your question.

**Question:** Mounting network drive in Windows 10 *from* Bash?

**Answer:** In Windows 10, open a *Cygwin* Bash prompt and issue:

```
net use V: //192.168.xxx.xxx/folder
```

Or a *cmder* bash prompt:

```
net use V: \\192.168.xxx.xxx\folder
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question nor explains what's the culprit. 2/3 of your answer is a polite rant, then you offer a workaround that requires installing extra software but doesn't offer any advantage over built-in `cmd`.

Comment: @gronostaj I explained that wsl does (or did) not fully support the feature: that's the culprit. I then answered the question in the title, showing how easy it should be, if the right tool is employed. Please note that the question is about `bash`, not built-in `cmd`.

Comment: You should delete this answer.